# When is `aws:PrincipalAccount` or `kms:CallerAccount` needed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-kms

What is the difference between the following two permission statements, assuming that they are used in resource-based permission policies in AWS?

1:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "*",
  "Resource": "*",
  "Principal": {"AWS: "123456789012"}
}
```

2:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "*",
  "Resource": "*",
  "Principal": {"AWS: "*"},
  "Condition: {
    "StringEquals": {
      "aws:PrincipalAccount": "123456789012" # or "kms:CallerAccount"
    }
  }
}
```

The documentation for [`aws:PrincipalAccount`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-principalaccount) doesn't have much to say.  The documentation for [`kms:CallerAccount`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/conditions-kms.html#conditions-kms-caller-account) says that

> The syntax for the Principal element does not provide a way to specify all identities in an AWS account.

However, I haven't been able to figure out what identities cannot be specified by the Principal constraint.